# Key being returned from Array not Value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My array has Mon - Sun, I am retrieving the current days value only and returning it to be used in JS.Here is how the Array looks.

```
Array(
[Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [active] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                )

            [start] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13:30
                )

            [end] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14:30
                )

        )
```

I also need to include, the array looks different by location because open hours are different. Here is an example of another location.

```
[Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [active] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => yes
                    [2] => yes
                )

            [start] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13:30
                    [1] => 16:45
                    [2] => 09:30
                )

            [end] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14:30
                    [1] => 17:00
                    [2] => 09:45
                )

        )
```

Here is $dayofweek

```
$dayofweek = date('l', strtotime($date));
```

Here is my foreach statement

```
foreach ($restarting as $data) {
    $close_now = $data[$dayofweek]['start'];
    $close_end = $data[$dayofweek]['end'];
    $booked_appt[] = $close_now;
    $booked_appt[] = $close_end;
}
```

Here is what is returned

Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => )

I should get 1:30 | 2:30

Comment: at least you should use `$data[$dayofweek]['start'][0]`, also check value of $dayofweek, print it

Comment: $dayofweek is returning wed

Comment: but key in array is `Wednesday` not `wed`

Comment: print `$data[$dayofweek]`

Comment: I am getting the same Array

Comment: NM print returns blanks

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why you have the 'yes' and the times '13:30' and '14:30' in an array within the array? It looks unnecessarily complicated.

If that's how it's supposed to be, you'll need to change this:

```
$close_now = $data[$dayofweek]['start'];
```

to this

```
$close_now = $data[$dayofweek]['start'][0];
```

Or you can simplify your $data array to contain less levels:

```
Array(
```

[Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [active] => 'yes',
            [start] => '13:30',
            [end] => '14:30'
        )

Comment: Its being pulled from a database, i have no control